# Getting "token is Invalid" with Okta OAuth request, why?

Tags: oauth, okta, okta-api

I am trying to call OKTA logout api from client. But it ends up with 404 Bad request. It expects 3 parameters: id_token_hint, post_logout_redirect_uri and state(optional). I am hitting request with format

```
https://{oktaDomain}.com/oauth2/default/v1/logout?id_token_hint={someToken}&post_logout_redirect_uri={someUri}
```

Purpose is just to wipe out the user session at OKTA by making some implicit call and redirecting user to `{someUri}`. This uri has been registered in OKTA configuration under Logout redirect uri, as per documentation. After all these efforts, whenever i am hitting request it return me 404 Bad request (token is Invalid)

The id_token_hint which i am passing is jwt id_token, which was returned at the time of authorizing user(login).

Not sure what i am missing ?

Is id_token_hint is some different token from id_token ?
or Is there any problem with URL itself ?

Comment: For the configuration you're using to log in, does your issuer end with "oauth2/default"? Are you using one of Okta's blog posts or sample apps to try this?

Comment: @MattRaible - Yes, i had started with okta's blog posts. Later, i got it working with developer account too with issuer "oauth2/default". But for some unknown reasons it is not working in prod yet even i tried generating new issuer too.